# Use dpcalendar event title as link attribut

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, fullcalendar, joomla2.5

Hope somebody is able to help, I'm struggling while trying to modify dpcalendar for joomla. What I want to achieve is to use the event title in the attribute of the link to the event, so I can use a css class on the title lateron. Title attribut is empty by default i.e.:

```
<a class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end" style="position: absolute; left: 531px; background-color: rgb(41, 82, 163); border-color: rgb(41, 82, 163); width: 86px; top: 131px;" href="/cms/index.php/agenda/gc-2-g44t57af3uq610qde4joeiulik_201502141815" data-original-title="" title="">
```

So I was looking for the line were the links are generated and I changed lines 4014 and 5376 in fullcalendar.js (i think thats the place) as follows:

```
html +=
        " class='" + classes.join(' ') + "'" +
        " style=" +
            "'" +
            "position:absolute;" +
            "top:" + seg.top + "px;" +
            "left:" + seg.left + "px;" +
            skinCss +
            "'" + "title='"+ htmlEscape(event.title)+ "'" +
        ">"
```

Unfortunately that does not work so far.. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thx!

Comment: I was able to give over the event title to the the link by changing the fullcalendar.min.js as follows: 
`<a href='"+aK(bG)+"'"}else{bI+="<div"}bI+=" class='"+bL.join(" ")+"' style='position:absolute;left:"+bK.left+"px;"+bF+"' title='"+bJ.title+"'>`
 however the data is always given to the attribut data-original-title and not to the attribut "title". I could actually use this attribut instead but it seems like tooltip refers to this one as well cause now it doesnt show the original content anymore..